# Removing duplicate from list using list comprehension lead to all Nones

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried the following code to remove duplicates from list using list comprehension

```
lists = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1]

unique_lists = []
[unique_lists.append(x) for x in lists if x not in unique_lists]
print(unique_lists)

unique_lists = []
g = [unique_lists.append(x) for x in lists if x not in unique_lists]
print(g)
```

The printed result are shown as below

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I'm trying to understand why the 2nd method (simply by assigning the list to g, returns all None? Thanks.

Comment: `append()` doesn't return anything. Just do the list comprehension without assigning the result to something. `unique_lists` will still get filled.

Comment: `lists` is 1 list with few numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `list.append()` always returns None.  The easy way to do what you want is to convert it to a set.

```
unique_lists = list(set(lists))
```

Comment: This will not preserve order.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I should have thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append` returns `None`. What you could do is use a set to remember the unique numbers:

```
lists = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1]

uniques = set()
unique_lists = [x for x in lists if not (x in uniques or uniques.add(x))]
```

Or a more efficient way would be to use how dict's act similar to a set while keeping insertion order (in python3+):

```
unique_lists = list(dict.fromkeys(lists))
```

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order) for more answers/explanation on how to remove dups from a list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a set to select the 1st occurrence of each distinct element will be more efficient than a list.  You can even embed this control set in the comprehension:

```
g = [x for s in [set()] for x in lists if x not in s and not s.add(x)]
```

if you're not concerned with performance, you could select the item based on the index of their first occurrence:

```
g = [x for i,x in enumerate(lists) if i==lists.index(x)]
```

There is also a trick you can do using a dictionary:

```
g = list(dict(zip(lists,lists)))
```